# Make an input radio button checked…using $(this) JQuery?

Tags: jquery, button, input, radio-button

I'm trying to set an input to be checked when it's button is clicked. I know how to do this using an ID like in the function below:

```
$(".buttonsQuestion50").click(function() {
$('#radio-1').prop('checked',true);
});
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make the same functionality work using $(this). The goal is as follows:

```
  $(".buttonsQuestion50").click(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
    });
```

Using $(this) in that way does not work. Any advice on how to make it work?

Thanks!

HTML for reference:

```
  <div class="button-box col-lg-12 col-xs-12"><!--
     --><button id="masters" type="button" class="fourButtons  buttonsQuestion50 btn btn-info   ">
         <input class='' type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-1"> Agree </button><!--
    --><button id="doctorate" type="button" class="fourButtons  buttonsQuestion50 btn btn-info   ">
         <input class='' type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-2"> Strongly Agree </button><!--
   --></div>
  <div class="button-box col-lg-12 col-xs-12"><!--
     --><button id="associates" type="button" class="fourButtons buttonsQuestion50 btn btn-info   ">
         <input class=''  type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-3">Disagree</button><!--
     --><button id="bachelors" type="button" class="fourButtons  buttonsQuestion50 btn btn-info   "> 
     <input class=''  type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-5">Strongly Disagree </button><!--
   --></div>
```

Comment: are ```$(".buttonsQuestion50")``` and ``` $(".buttonsQuestion50")``` the same?

Comment: @DegenSharew That's true. It's the #radio-1 and $(this) that are different

Comment: ok then you need to show us the html

Comment: @DegenSharew Done

Comment: @DegenSharew It's the first one

Comment: A radio button inside a push button... is that a good idea?

Comment: Thanks for all of the help @DegenSharew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** method to do what you need, but the markup is not `W3C` valid. You shouldn't have inputs inside buttons. You can do a test validation of your code **[here](https://validator.w3.org/)**.

```js
$(".buttonsQuestion50").click(function() {
   $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', true);
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-box col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
  <!--
     -->
  <button id="masters" type="button" class="fourButtons  buttonsQuestion50 btn btn-info   ">
    <input class='' type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-1">Agree</button>
  <!--
    -->
  <button id="doctorate" type="button" class="fourButtons  buttonsQuestion50 btn btn-info   ">
    <input class='' type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-2">Strongly Agree</button>
  <!--
   -->
</div>
<div class="button-box col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
  <!--
     -->
  <button id="associates" type="button" class="fourButtons buttonsQuestion50 btn btn-info   ">
    <input class='' type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-3">Disagree</button>
  <!--
     -->
  <button id="bachelors" type="button" class="fourButtons  buttonsQuestion50 btn btn-info   ">
    <input class='' type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-5">Strongly Disagree</button>
  <!--
   -->
</div>
```

I would recommend you to use `div` elements instead of buttons, or any other fitted elements, as long as you use `Bootstrap` classes they will look the same as the buttons, like this:

```js
$(".buttonsQuestion50").click(function() {
  $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-box col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
  <!--
     -->
  <div id="masters" class="fourButtons  buttonsQuestion50 btn btn-info   ">
    <input class='' type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-1">Agree</div>
  <!--
    -->
  <div id="doctorate" class="fourButtons  buttonsQuestion50 btn btn-info   ">
    <input class='' type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-2">Strongly Agree</div>
  <!--
   -->
</div>
<div class="button-box col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
  <!--
     -->
  <div id="associates" class="fourButtons buttonsQuestion50 btn btn-info   ">
    <input class='' type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-3">Disagree</div>
  <!--
     -->
  <div id="bachelors" class="fourButtons  buttonsQuestion50 btn btn-info   ">
    <input class='' type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-5">Strongly Disagree</div>
  <!--
   -->
</div>
```

Comment: plus one for understanding the question ;) I did not realize the button was wrapping the radio input

Comment: Awesome. This was immensely helpful. Thanks for taking the time!